# JQ+Mobile : Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile, preventdefault

I just configure a use of jq-mobile and jq to hold Android mobile events (particularly swipe ans taphold ) into an application using same code (with some code blocks switching device and browser cases) and I get the error :

**jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3 Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener** due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080

- preventDefault @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
- s.move @ jquery.mobile.custom.min.js?ver= v1.4.5 custom packaged - 2017-04-15:3
- dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
- r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3

Into the same trace just before I get too :

**jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:45 JQMIGRATE: Global events are undocumented and deprecated**

- migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:45
- jQuery.event.trigger @ jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:631
- $.fn.setCookieNotice @ front.js?ver=1.2.38:19
- cnHandleScroll @ front.js?ver=1.2.38:62
- dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
- r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3

**My questions :**

- How can I find into the code (Wordpress with 50 plugins and my owns) what is not accepted, deprecated and generates the error ?
- Must I try to not load jquery-migrate and detect errors by this way ?
- How to find code which fires deprecated events calls ?
- Which other way to solve the problem

Thanks

Trebly

---

Note : even there are 14 threads related to same subject I have not found any which ask the same question. I is the reason I post it as not duplicate